Model appears stretched out in Object Mode
This is my first attempt at using Blender so I'm not quite sure what I did wrong. I had modeled the arms and hands away from the body at first before moving them back towards the body. When I had opened Object mode I noticed that some of the faces on the arms had been stretched out and were only visible in modes like Object mode. I haven't gotten to any rigging so I'm not quite sure where I went wrong.
Thank you so much for your time!




Hello, your link asks for an authorization, please authorize or use another platform   ;)

Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Press AltH and you'll see some hidden vertices, delete them.

+1. Far easier than mine.

@StefLAncien Yes I think you've made a bit too complicated  ;)

(Using Blender 3.6.8)

Unless some complex tracking/debug using GeometryNodes modifier is your objective, moonboots "just one click" solution should be favoured.

It seems that there are "ghost" points/edges/faces, not editable.

Fig. 1 - In Object Mode, extra faces are protruding from arm and hand.

Fig. 2 - These extra faces are not displayed in Edit Mode. But it is to notice at the bottom right of the screen capture that even selecting All, only 851 out of 963 vertices are selected. There are also some unselected edges and faces.

Fig. 3 - After selecting All, a vertex group is made from selection using the menu entry Vertex > Vertex Groups > Assign to New Group. This VG is named "Good".

Fig. 4 - Adding a GeometryNodes modifier to the faulty object gives the opportunity through a Viewer node to visualize vertices not belonging to the "Good" VG. It is to notice that the VG is accessible as a Named Attribute.

Fig. 5 - An other GeometryNodes modifier attached to the faulty object is deleting all Points with a zero weight, removing extra vertices.

Fig. 6 - After applying the GN modifier, 851 out of 851 vertices are selected/selectable in Edit Mode. However, 13 edges and 25 faces are remaining un-selectable.

Fig. 7 - More classical clean-up is required as illustrated here using the menu entry Select > Select All by Trait > Interior Faces.
Resources: 
